# C# Threading with HttpRequestMessage headers

Tags: c#, multithreading, web, request, task

I have a number of tasks running concurrently making asynchronous web requests. They all reference a header string which contains an authorisation token required to make a successful request. After some duration the token expires and a new one must be generated for future web requests to work. To do this, each Web Request has a fallback where if it returns an unauthorised error it will send off a new token request and then apply that to the global token string, and then re-run the request.

Imagine I have Tasks A & B performing asynchronous requests. They both receive an unauthorised request error and attempt to generate a new token, however Task A received it before Task B and so has already began the request for a new token.

What would be the best way to ensure the entire operation is thread safe? So that when Task B goes to request a token it realises that Task A is already in the process of doing so, so Task B no longer attempts to send of a token request, but simply waits for Task A to finish and return a value that they both can use.

I thought of simply using a lock, but Task B would only wait to re-generate the token itself and not realise that it can use the recently regenerated value of Task A.

Comment: Additionally, there may be any number of concurrent tasks running. I simply used two in this article to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this simply by utilising a lock. I was vastly overthinking my initial approach.